# The number of times head show up is more than no.of times tail show up in four trials

Tags: probability

> A fair coin is tossed independently four times . The probability of event  "the no. Of times head show up is more than the no. Of times tails shows up" is

The answer is $5/16$.

I did

$${_4\mathsf C}_4 (1/2)^4 (1/2)^0 + {_4\mathsf C}_3(1/2)^3 (1/2)$$

Is it correct ?

Comment: What do you mean by is it correct? Do you want us to check your logic? or were you too lazy to compute that? Also, I'm guessing you meant ${_4 \mathsf C }_4$. Also also, formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I've some solved papaer .of Gate.so im solving those and in this problem my answer is not matched .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct. You claimed that you calculated it, but it simply looks like you meant ${_4 \mathsf C}_4$ **not** ${_5\mathsf C }_4$. If you fix that, then it is correct. In other words, the number of heads is 3 or 4 are the only two cases where the number of heads is greater than the number of tails, this will result in the correct answer. Because the events are disjoint, we can add up the probabilities and so
$${_4\mathsf C }_3 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^1+{_4\mathsf C }_4  \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^0 = \frac{5}{16} $$

Answer (score 1):

There are two combinations of tails only coming up once or not at all:

All heads:  This can only happen 1 successful way.

Or once tails and three heads:  The tail can come 1st, 2nd, 3rd, or 4th: So there are 4 succesful ways.

There are $2^4=16$ possible outcomes in total as 4 tosses each have 2 outcomes.

That makes a total of 5 successful ways out of 16 possible outcomes in total:

$$\frac{1+4}{2^4}=\frac{5}{16}$$